# Java WebService checking for SSL

Tags: java, ssl, wsdl

I've developed a WSDL webservice in Java and I need to check if the connection/call/request was made via SSL (In short, only accept SSL connections/requests). Is this possible? 
I wasn't able to find anything relating to it, but I'm probably searching wrong.

Comment: Web service code does not have to differ, you setup web server to accept htpps requests. https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=create+ssl+webservice&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr&ei=4g0lUtbRAcrR7Aaq0oHwBA

Comment: But is there anyway to do a second check on the Java side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do a second check on the Java side. Just define the resource correctly in `web.xml.` If you must check it for some reason, just check `ServletRequest.isSecure()`.